# Expression for calculating the longest edge of a polygon rectangle in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, distance, expression, fill

I want to be able to calculate the longest edge of a rectangle polygon to create an expression for a style.

The styled rectangles will have variable orientations, widths and lengths.

I want to use this longest length to create an expression for the spacing of the Line Pattern Fill of the polygon style. The spacing will be set to 1/3 of the longest length of the polygon, so that the rectangle is visually divided into three segments (the rotation is already set to be `-(main_angle($geometry))`).

As an example, the distance of the longest edge is 3.501 m, which divided by three equals 1.167 m. This value (1.167 m) is set as my spacing. The effect is what I am after, I just want to automate this without manually calculating the 1/3 of the longest edge!

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Use this expression, and remember to set the units to **Map Units** and **Clipping** to **Clip Lines Before Render**.

```
array_max(array_foreach(
    geometries_to_array(segments_to_lines($geometry)),
    length(@element)
)) / 3
```

[image: 1]

Comment: What version of QGIS is this solution for?

Comment: @Cushen, 3.30 ‘s-Hertogenbosch.